# Product of a singular and continuous measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, singular-measures

Suppose we have a function $f(x,y)\geq 0$ and we integrate it with respect to a measure $\mu=\mu_{\mathrm{a.c.}}+\mu_{\mathrm{disc}}+\mu_{\mathrm{s.c}}$. Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\iint f(x,y)d\mu(x)d\mu(y)=\iint f(x,y)d\mu_{\mathrm{a.c.}}(x)d\mu_{\mathrm{a.c.}}(y)+
\iint f(x,y)d\mu_{\mathrm{disc}}(x)d\mu_{\mathrm{disc}}(y)\\+\iint f(x,y)d\mu_{\mathrm{s.c}}(x)d\mu_{\mathrm{s.c}}(y),
\end{equation}
since for all other combinations of measures the integral is 0? Why/why not?

Comment: "for all other combinations of measures the integral is 0" Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried an example?  Say, $f(x,y)=1$?

Comment: Ok, the actual question is exactly whether $\iint d\mu_a(x)d\mu_b(y)=0$ for different $a$ and $b$ -  combinations of a.c., s.c. and discrete.